# Cloning Textmate's functionality with Vim

Tags: vim, text-editor, text

Tips and advice on how to clone [Textmate](http://macromates.com)'s functionality in Ubuntu. I've done some research on this in the past and I know this information is valuable to the community.

Comment: How is gedit related?

Comment: In a previous version of this question it was. ;-) I'll remove that tag.

Comment: You should specify the features you use that you're looking to port over. It's a really broad question depending on what you're looking to get.

Answer (score 8):

## snipMate.vim

For Textmate style snippet expansion in Vim.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540

Answer (score 6):

### Command-T

The [Command-T](https://wincent.com/products/command-t/) plugin is un-do-without-able. It replicates TextMate's Go To File... functionality very nicely, plus of course you can set your own keymapping, and have files open in split windows, tabs, etc.

Answer (score 3):

## NerdTree

For file exploration in Vim.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658

Answer (score 2):

If vim is not a requirement (in the title you said Vim but in the text you said how to clone textmate in ubuntu) you should take a shot on emacs.

In emacs you can have a closer textmate experience, with a snap-open (ido-mode) snippets with yasnippet (compatible with textmate snippets) and an editing style a little closer to what you get on textmate.

Comment: Appreciated, but I wanted this community wiki to be for Vim.

Answer (score 2):

[Fuzzy Finder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) was written by someone [returning](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/10/10/coming-home-to-vim) to Vim from Textmate.

Answer (score 2):

try this [Coming Home To Vim](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/)

Comment: [Vim for php programmers](http://conf.phpquebec.com/slides/2009/Vim-for-php-programmers-phpquebec_2009.pdf) And
[perl hacks on vim](http://www.slideshare.net/c9s/perlhacksonvim)

Answer (score 0):

## pathogen.vim

Replicate TextMate's bundle functionality. After installing pathogen, you can drop plugins into a 'bundle' directory, pathogen manipulates vim's runtimepath so everything gets loaded.

This is especially great for using vim plugins which live on github. If you keep your config in a git repo, you can use submodules to help you keep everything up to date.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332

Answer (score 0):

i've used vim and all its plugins brother if you want a more cooler experiance and you dont want to spend all your time learning just the editor  try gedit-plugins available in repo and check its site too " best for programming " :) ubuntu rocks